# Plotting graph and adding twinx() with seaborn

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, twinx

I am plotting a graph using seaborn, the code is:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
ax2 = ax.twinx()

sns.barplot(x="dt_mvtc", y="qtde_t0",
         data=df_grafico_merge.query('t0_def_qtt==1'),color='blue',ax=ax)

sns.lineplot(x="dt_mvtc",y='qtde_t12', hue='t12_def_qtt', style='t12_def_qtt',
         data=df_grafico_merge.query('t0_def_qtt==1'),markers= True, color='orange', ax=ax2)

plt.xlabel("Data")
plt.ylabel("Quantidade")
plt.title('Qtde de registros por data e t0=1')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

for axis in [ax.yaxis]:
    formatter = ScalarFormatter()
    formatter.set_scientific(True)
    axis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

plt.show()
```

And the output is:

[image: Output]

why the x axis are like that? Since I am using `x=dt_mvtc` in both, why are they mixing?
Just for comparison, when I comment the line `ax2 = ax.twinx()`, the axis outputs right (that is, with dates rotated 90 and readable), so my problem is using the `twinx()`, but I do not where it is wrong. Any help?

Comment: Writing `ax2 = ax.twinx()` makes `ax2` the "current ax", upon which `plt.xticks()` is acting.  You could try to follow `ax2 = ax.twinx()` with `plt.sca(ax)` to set `ax` again as "current ax".  Alternatively, you could rotate the ticks via `for tick in ax.get_xticklabels(): tick.set_rotation(90)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.xticks` only uses the last subplot axis that is called. To get the rotated xticks add:

```
for ax_ in fig.axes:
    plt.sca(ax_)
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```